# Concatenar números en CCs

Tags: c, ccs

Tengo el siguiente problema con el compilador CCS para pic. La función concatena números, pero solo funciona con números de una cifra por ejemplo el 1 con el 5 me muestra 15.

Bien, ahora si hago el 21 con el 56 por ejemplo me da un número errado. ¿Qué puede ser? 
pd: cuando lo pruebo con un compilador de C me anda bien.

```
int concat(int x, int y)
{
    int temp = y;
    while (y != 0)
    {
        x = x * 10;
        y = y / 10;
    }
    return x + temp;
}

int x = 2;
int y = 4;
aux = concat(x, y);
printf(lcd_putc, "%u", aux);
```

Comment: `concat(x,y)` y `concatenate(x,y)` ?

Comment: si , perdon copie mal. Alguna idea?

Comment: cual es la salida esperada para 21 y 56? puedes poner el funcionamiento esperado?. probé el código en ideone y funciona bien: https://ideone.com/Dk5fQq

Comment: @Eugenio Creo que tu problema se debe al flag `%u`. Como puedes ver, se trata de un compilador de C que es diferente a los demás,  andaba viendo en sus foros para buscar una pista, puedes probar con imprimir el entero de la siguiente forma: `printf(lcd_putc, "%i", aux);` ?  Aunque con `%u` no debería haber problema, imprime el número como `unsigned int`...

Comment: la salida esperada para 21 y 65 seria 2165. El código funciona en cualquier compilador de c menos en el CCs que es para pic, supongo que va por allí la cosa. Gracias

Comment: ya he probado cambiar por %i pero nada . Gracias

Comment: Funciona bien, no da número errado.

Comment: @EugenioLiberatoriSvoger En C debería funcionar esto, `printf("%i", aux);`, el algoritmo lo probé y funciona bien.

Comment: prueba printf("%4u", aux);

Answer (score 1):

En CCS PICC el tipo "int" es de 8 bits. Puesto que estás manejando números mayores a 255 deberías usar un tipo más grande como "int16".